# Using zlib with mingw

Tags: c++, zlib

I am trying to read a test.zip file using the zlib library and extract the contents. My requirement is to read each file and output content (unzipped) first to memory and then to a file.

I tried the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zlib.h>

using namespace std;


#define LINE 1024

int main()
{
    const char *filename = "hello.zip";
    gzFile inFileZ = gzopen(filename, "rb");
    if (inFileZ == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Failed to gzopen %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }
    unsigned char unzipBuffer[8192];
    unsigned int unzippedBytes;
    std::vector<unsigned char> unzippedData;
    while (true) {
        unzippedBytes = gzread(inFileZ, unzipBuffer, 8192);
        if (unzippedBytes > 0) {
            cout << unzippedBytes << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < unzippedBytes; i++) {
                cout << unzipBuffer[i];
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    gzclose(inFileZ);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the above example from the web. It was mentioned that `gzread` inflates the contents and fills the buffer (here `unzipBuffer`). However when I tried to print it, it was printing the same contents of the .zip file (example `PK.....` with non readable code).

I believe I am not correctly using the APIs of zlib. However I could not find an example related to this. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

The zlib library does not directly process the zip format.  zlib provides the raw deflate compression and decompression that you would need to process deflated zip entries, as well as a CRC-32 calculation facility.  However you would need to write your own code or use another library to parse and process the zip format.

gzip is not zip.  They are two completely different formats that use, or may use, the same raw compression format within.

Comment: thanks for your comments. Can you share some examples which I can use? This will help a lot.

Comment: google is your friend.  You would find things like libzip, libarchive, minizip, etc.

Comment: I tried there but did not find a good example. I saw the cpipe.c from zlib.net but I did not find how I can use this code very specific to my requirement. But thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 0):

THere is known ZIP reimplementation in C, from http://www.info-zip.org/. They have Windows DLL which I believe could be used to do what you want

UPDATE

some example is here
http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Compression/Unzipping_Files/article.asp

Comment: you are referring to a different library. I have to use zlib.

Comment: @programmer well, `zlib` is just stream compressing/decompressing, it won't help with file-on-disk format. UnZip from Info-Zip is doing both: dealing with file format and uncompressing as well. It could be compiled into Windows DLL and there is even example in the distribution how to use DLL